Ubuntu 24.04 installing problem on Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5
I have a new laptop Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5. And I'd like to install Ubuntu 24.04 here. I created a USB Stick, loaded and launched the installation process. It seems everything is fine but before the finish screen it shows me an error: Something went wrong.
And after rebooting it shows the screen that there is any OS and any boot menu.
I've tried to install Ubuntu 24, Debian 12 - and nothing works.
Can anyone help me to handle with this issue? What do I do wrong?
Thanks.



Do you have latest firmware for UEFI and if SSD for SSD? New 24.04.1 will be out at end of week. May be worth waiting. But most issues being fixed were with upgrades, not new installs. But it does get many other updates. Some Lenovo have UEFI settings locking ESP - efi system partition preventing install of boot loader/grub. Check UEFI settings. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494747

The problem was that Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't support 13th gen intel core i7. I used this page to check:
https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iot
And when I selected the 13th gen intel it showed that I can install Ubuntu 22.04. Then I downloaded it, created a bootable USB Stick via balenaEtcher and it was installed without any problems.
Probably it may help to someone.

Thanks for taking the trouble to post your solution.
